# How to fix extra data appearing in the ERB generated HTML

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I am following `ruby-on-rails` instruction guide to creating a simple `blog` web application: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#generating-a-controller

All my project files are pretty much the same as the ones in the guide.

`app/views/articles/show.html.erb`

```
<p>
  <strong>Title:</strong>
  <%= @article.title %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Text:</strong>
  <%= @article.text %>
</p>

<h2>Add a comment:</h2>
<%= render 'comments/form' %>

<h2>Comments (<%= @article.comments.count %>)</h2>
<%= render 'comment_section' %>
<%#= render @article.comments %>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_article_path(@article) %> |
<%= link_to 'Delete', article_path(@article),
            method: :delete,
            data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'} %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', articles_path %>
```

---

`app/views/comments/_form.html.erb`

```
<%= form_with(model: [@article, @article.comments.build], local: true) do |form| %>
  <p>
    <%= form.label :commenter %><br>
    <%= form.text_field :commenter %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= form.label :body %><br>
    <%= form.text_area :body %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= form.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

---

`app/views/articles/_comment_section.html.erb`

```
<% if @article.comments.count > 0 %>
  <%= render @article.comments %>
<% else %>
  <p>There are no comments yet!</p>
<% end %>
```

---

`app/views/comments/_comment.html.erb`

```
<p>
  <strong>Commenter:</strong>
  <%= comment.commenter %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Comment:</strong>
  <%= comment.body %>
</p>

<p>
  <%= link_to 'Delete comment', [comment.article, comment],
              method: :delete,
              data: {confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete this comment?'}
  %>
```

---

A simple article with no comments works as expected:

[image: Empty comment section]

However, when showing an article with some actual comments, an extra empty comment gets displayed at the end:

[image: Single comment]

When I try to delete that comment I get the following error (11 in the path is the article_id):

[image: Deletion error]

Deleting other comments works fine.

Rest of the files that I think might be relevant:

`app/config/routes.rb`

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'welcome/index'

  resources :articles do
    resources :comments
  end

  root 'welcome#index'
end
```

---

`app/models/article.rb`

```rb
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
  validates :title, presence: true, length: {minimum: 5}
end
```

---

`app/models/comment.rb`

```rb
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :article
end
```

---

`app/controllers/articles_controller.rb`

```rb
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @articles = Article.all
  end

  def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @article = Article.new
  end

  def edit
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)
    if @article.save
      redirect_to @article
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def update
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])

    if @article.update(article_params)
      redirect_to @article
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    @article.destroy

    redirect_to articles_path
  end

  private

  def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
  end
end
```

---

`app/controllers/comments_controller.rb`

```rb
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
    @comment = @article.comments.create(comment_params)
    redirect_to article_path(@article)
  end

  def destroy
    @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
    @comment = @article.comments.find(params[:id])
    @comment.destroy
    redirect_to article_path(@article)
  end

  private
  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:commenter, :body)
  end
end
```

I'm using:

`ruby 2.6.5p114`

`Rails 6.0.0`

`sqlite3 3.8.7.2`

`RubyMine 2019.2.3`

I'm developing on Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why this is happening is this line:

`<%= form_with(model: [@article, @article.comments.build], local: true) do |form| %>`

The part that says `@article.comments.build` is building an empty comment on the article.  If there are no comments on the article and you were to print out `@article.comments.count` it would be zero.  It does this because `@article.comments.count` runs a query, and since the blank comment isn't saved yet, it doesn't count it against the comments count.

As a side note, `@article.comments.size` would return 1, since in this case it returns the size of the relation with the blank comment.  This is why you don't get a blank comment when the article has no comments.

However if you were to already have a comment and print out `@article.comments.count`, it would be 1 because now you have a saved comment in the database.  This renders your comments out on the page now.  The thing is that there is a blank comment inside of the `@article.comments` return value.  This gets printed out to the screen, and since it doesn't have an id, the route for delete gets rendered like this `/article/11/comments` without a comment id.  This route does not exist, so you get an error.

One possible way to fix this would be to change this line in your `comment_section` partial from this:

`<%= render @article.comments %>`

to this:

`<%= render @article.comments.select { |comment| comment.persisted? %>`

UPDATE:

I think that arieljuod's solution is even cleaner, to change this:

`<%= form_with(model: [@article, @article.comments.build], local: true) do |form| %>`

To this:

`<%= form_with(model: [@article, Comment.new], local: true) do |form| %>`

Comment: Instead of skipping the non persisted comment, maybe changing `@article.comments.build` to `Comment.new` is enough and cleaner.

Comment: @arieljuod, I agree, that would be a little cleaner and something I would probably do myself :D

Answer (score 0):

in your `views/comments/_comment.html.erb`

change

```
  <%= link_to 'Delete comment', [comment.article, comment],
          method: :delete,
          data: {confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete this comment?'} %>
```

to

```
  <%= link_to 'Delete comment', comment_path(comment),
          method: :delete,
          data: {confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete this comment?'} %>
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but changed it a bit. Instead of `comment_path` I used `article_comment_path`. Doesn't work though